# jQuery: why doesn't jQuery.inArray() work?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

[image]

As shown in the image, I just do inArray on an array, looking for a node. and $previously_selected_node and the item at index 37 in $shapes are the same object.... so... why isn't it working?

EDIT:
I found another way to search after one of the aswerers postedd his answer:

```
var result = -1;
jQuery.each(shapes, function(key, value){
    if (value.id == shape.id){
        result = key;
    }
});
return result;
```

apparently, part of my problem is that I can't return in the middle of a loop. (I was returning the instant a match was found, which was causing some issues.)

Comment: Does `$shapes` have `length`?

Comment: $shapes.length is undefined... so.. then it's not actually an array, even though I assign values to it like $shapes[id] = val;  so... how do I search through it then?

Comment: Usually, when questions are of the form 'Why doesn't `<insert name of popular library function>` work?' come along - it is being used incorrectly. `$shapes` may not be an **Array**, also comparison of objects is prone to trouble.

Comment: So, how do I search through whatever object this is?

Comment: @TheLindyHop, using [`jQuery.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/), but, have a mind to how you compare elements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your object is not an array.
`$.inArray` only work on *array-like objects* with a `length` and a set of properties named `0` through *length - 1*.

You need to search your non-array manually.
For example, you could use a `for` / `in` loop to loop through all properties that actually exist and see if any of them match your object:

```
for (var key in $shapes) {
    if ($shapes[key] === yourObject) {
        //Match!
    }
}
```

Comment: how? I've tried .each, for loops... not really sure what this object is either.

Comment: nice, I found a similar solution, added to OP

Answer (score 3):

You're doing it the wrong way round. It's actually `$.inArray(value, array)`.

And as others already stated: inArray is for arrays, not for objects.