# Bug in jQuery 1.9.1 with function $.inArray

Tags: javascript, jquery

I recently came to conclusion that $.inArray is not working.
I researched everywhere, saw similar threads to [jQuery: why doesn't jQuery.inArray() work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7556943/jquery-why-doesnt-jquery-inarray-work)

But still I see it as a jQuery Bug.
Because I have a ARRAY which I am using in $.inArray

Here is the console.log

**var testArray** value is:

```
["1", "15"]
```

which is obvisouly an array in JavaScript.

And I am using command

```
if($.inArray(14, testArray))
  alert("14 should not be in array. Isn't it?");
```

I Also tried following, but stil same problem:

```
if(jQuery.inArray('14', testArray))
  alert("14 should not be in array. Isn't it?");
```

Comment: You forgot to ask a question..!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

jQuery's [`$.inArray`](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/) method returns an index of where the value is found, or `-1` if it is not found. It just so happens that `-1` is truthy (convert it to a boolean by running `!!-1`), which will evaluate to true. In order to more reliably use this method, compare its return value rather than merely using it as a condition:

```
if ( $.inArray(14, ["1", "15"]) > -1 ) {
    alert( "Value has been found" );
}
```

This is stated very clearly in the [online documentation](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/).

If you're looking for a simpler convention when using this approach, you can invert the bits of the operand and convert `-1` to `0` and `0` to `-1`:

```
if ( ~$.inArray(14, ["1", "15"]) )
```

Answer (score 4):

`$.inArray` returns `-1` if item is not found. So jQuery `isArray` does work properly. That's why when you run your test code:

```
if ($.inArray(14, testArray)) {
    alert("14 should not be in array. Isn't it?");
}
```

you see alert. Of course, because `-1` is not falsy.